# FCM Web push notification unable to register the default service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am using FCM web app notification for send notification to browser.
**I Got The following errors :

- 1.A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.  ------ firebase-messaging-sw.js
- 2..Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
- 3.Error -> messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration
- 4.Error Message -> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a
  ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when
  fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵ 
  at
  https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase-messaging.js:6:14342↵
  at **

My code below.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "APIKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "fir-cloudmessaging-d3607.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-cloudmessaging-d3607.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-cloudmessaging-d3607",
    storageBucket: "fir-cloudmessaging-d3607.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDERID123456789"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
  // ...
  console.log(messaging.getToken());
 // return messaging.getToken();
})
.then(function(token){
  console.log(token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This error message means that FCM can't retrieve the code for the service worker from `/firebase-messaging-sw.js`. Matt gave some hints here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/84, or have a look at some of the [previous reports of the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=messaging%2Ffailed-serviceworker-registration)